Folium filter markers dynamically by property
I have the following code to draw circles at different locations, using Folium:
import folium

data = [
    {"lat": 37.7749, "lon": -122.4194, "value": 10, "name": "Location A"},
    {"lat": 34.0522, "lon": -118.2437, "value": 20, "name": "Location B"},
    {"lat": 40.7128, "lon": -74.0060, "value": 15, "name": "Location C"},
    {"lat": 41.8781, "lon": -87.6298, "value": 5, "name": "Location D"}
]

# Initialize the map centered at an average location
m = folium.Map(location=[39.8283, -98.5795], zoom_start=4)

# Add circles to the map with custom attribute for value
for item in data:
    circle = folium.Circle(
        location=[item["lat"], item["lon"]],
        radius=100000,  # Radius in meters
        color='blue',
        fill=True,
        fill_color='blue',
        fill_opacity=0.6,
        popup=f"{item['name']}: {item['value']}",
        data_value=item["value"]
    )
    circle.add_to(m)

m.save('map.html')

I'd like to do some kind of filter by input value, meaning that, for example, entering in a text box number 20 would make markers with lower value than 20 to be hidden. I've seen in Folium things like TreeLayerControl, which is very similar to my goal, but I can't group my markers, since I expect to plot many circles and it would be useless from a UX point of view
